# JQuery live + Disqus / Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, live, disqus

I'm using the following function to overload my website url links with Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.insite').live("click", function(ev) {
        if ( history.pushState ) history.pushState( {}, document.title, $(this).attr('href'));
        ev.preventDefault();
        $('#content').fadeOut().load($(this).attr('href')+' #content', function() {
                $(this).fadeIn();
            });
    });
});
```

I would like to know if it's possible to integrate Google Analytics tracking and Disqus loading into the function. 
This is the code I have tried to load disqus but it loads comments from another websites for some reasons:

```
window.disqus_no_style = true;
$.getScript("http://disqus.com/forums/mnml/embed.js")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can just put the Google Analytics function directly in the event call, placing the new virtual URL in the second parameter.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.insite').live("click", function(ev) {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if ( history.pushState ) history.pushState( {}, document.title, href);
        ev.preventDefault();
        $('#content').fadeOut().load(href+' #content', function() {
                $(this).fadeIn();
                _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', href ]);
            });
    });
});
```

(I've edited the function to cache the `href` within the event, since its inefficient to spin up 3 (now 4) separate jQuery objects for a value that will be fixed for each call. )